# How do I find if an element contains a specific class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if an element contains a certain child class using JQUERY.

I tried:

```
if ($('#myElement').has('.myClass')) {
   do work son
}
```

Didn't work.

My html code is laid out like this:

```
<div id="myElement">
    <img>
    <span>something</span>
    <span class="myClass">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myElement").getElementsByClassName("myClass").length`

Comment: @Raynos: ha ha... too much javascript. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be to search for `.myClass` as a child of `#myElement`:

```
if($('#myElement .myClass')).length > 0)
```

If you only want first level children, you'd use `>`

```
if($('#myElement > .myClass')).length > 0)
```

---

Another way would be passing a selector to `find` and checking for any results:

```
if($('#myElement').find('.myClass').length > 0)
```

Or for first level children only:

```
if($('#myElement').children('.myClass').length > 0)
```

Comment: That doesn't work :/ I don't think that checks the child elements, just the element given.

Answer (score 5):

Just use QS

`var hasClass = document.getElementById("myElement").querySelector(".myClass");`

or you could recurse over the children

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElement");

var hasClass = recursivelyWalk(element.childNodes, function hasClass(node) {
  return node.classList.contains("myClass");
});

function recursivelyWalk(nodes, cb) {
    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        var ret = cb(node);
        if (ret) {
            return ret;
        }
        if (node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length) {
            var ret = recursivelyWalk(node.childNodes, cb);
            if (ret) {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using [`recursivelyWalk`](https://gist.github.com/1473536) and [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) (which can be shimmed).

Alternatively you can use jQuery

`$("#myElement .myClass").hasClass("myClass");`

or if you want composite operations without jQuery then try [`NodeComposite`](https://github.com/Raynos/NodeComposite)

`NodeComposite.$("#myElement *").classList.contains("myClass");`

Comment: why didn't you use getelementsbyclassname as per your comment? ie?

Comment: @naveen querySelector is shorter :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if($('#myElement').children('.myClass').length) {
    // Do what you need to
}
```

The jQuery object returns an array, which has the `.length` property. The above code checks if there are any `.myClass` children in `#myElement` and, if there are (when `.length` isn't 0), executes the code inside the `if()` statement.

Here's a more explicit version:

```
if($('#myElement').children('.myClass').length > 0) {
    // Do what you need to
}
```

You could always use `$('#myElement .myClass').length` too, but `$.children()` is clearer to some. To find elements that aren't *direct* children, use `$.find()` in place of `$.children()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($.contains($('#myElement'), $('.myClass'))){
    alert("True");
}
else{alert("False")};
```

Comment: Using `$('#myElement').children('.myClass').length` is cleaner and more obvious in meaning, as well as being less complex and possibly a bit faster.